# What happened to the Journal of Game Development?

Tags: books

The lengthy mission statement from [its website](http://web.archive.org/web/20080614200102/http://www.jogd.com/) states:

> The lack of game-specific research has prevented many in the academic community from embracing game development as a serious field of study. The Journal of Game Development (JOGD), however, provides a much-needed, peer-reviewed, medium of communication and the raison d'etre for serious academic research focused solely on game-related issues. The JOGD provides the vehicle for disseminating research and findings indigenous to the game development industry. It is an outlet for peer-reviewed research that will help validate the work and garner acceptance for the study of game development by the academic community.  JOGD will serve both the game development industry and academic community by presenting leading-edge, original research, and theoretical underpinnings that detail the most recent findings in related academic disciplines, hardware, software, and technology that will directly affect the way games are conceived, developed, produced, and delivered.

The Journal of Game Development was established in 2003. It's hard to find any information about the issues but at four issues per year, I estimate the last issue was distributed sometime in 2005 or 2006. It had a good editorial board of college professors and a founding editor from Ubisoft. The list of articles looks good. The price was reasonable.

**So what happened to it?** Its website recently went down but you can see [the last Archive.org version](http://web.archive.org/web/20080614200102/http://www.jogd.com/).

The editor-in-chief is a professor at my school so I intend to ask him in person in a week or two, but I thought I'd see what you might be able to dig up about it first. Of course I will be sure to add an answer with his official word on the matter at that time.

Comment: When you talk to him, you might also mention that the personal page pointed to in his bio (rmichaelyoung.com) doesn't exist anymore either.

Comment: Any word on what happened to it?  Did you get a chance to talk to your instructor?

Comment: Well I haven't been able to catch him. I sent him an email a number of days ago but he apparently ignored it (he is an extremely busy guy but it still surprises me that he would ignore a student email).

Comment: Have you tried looking into/asking Charles River Media about the journal?

Comment: Charles River Media was acquired by Cenage at some point.  I wonder if it ceased publication when that happened?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I pitched the concept for the Journal of Game Development to Charles River Media after we'd seen success on a few of the Game Programming Gems books. At the time we were starting to see a surge in the number of schools offering game development courses, or at least interested in offering them. We couldn't find anywhere that professors at these institutions could successfully publish research and have it be considered an accredited journal that would contribute toward their tenure requirements. Of course there were venues like SIGCHI and SIGGRAPH, but nothing specifically game-focused, and both of those organizations were only slightly interested in game development at the time. So this was the idea for the journal, to be a place where valuable research could be published, that would be a resource for both students and professors -- a place that we could hopefully, ten years later, see the evolution of game development.

Unfortunately it was not to be. We needed the journal to publish a particular number of volumes per year for a few years in order for it to gain its status as an accredited journal. Between challenges getting institutions to purchase it, and challenges getting all of us who were so busy to focus on it, we had a difficult time keeping a consistent publishing pace. I'm sad about it in retrospect, as I still feel it would have been an exceedingly valuable resource, and the people working on it were a great team.

Comment: Unfortunate indeed. The entire community would have benefited from such a resource. Maybe you chose a bad time to launch such initiative? Maybe now that game development is starting to see a larger and broader audience of consumers and programmers interested would be a better time?

Comment: Hi and welcome, Mark! I hope you're planning to stay on Gamedev SE. I like your books a lot ;)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the publisher, Charles River Media, made a business decision to stop printing the journal.

However there are other, more area-specific journals for game development in existence (i.e. journals about AI, networking, etc. - one specific aspect of game development).